# Build an Stereoscopic player in Android with Exoplayer

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, 360-virtual-reality

Im developing an app that allows to the user to see a 360 video in streaming from an IP camera called `Insta360`. With `Exoplayer` and using `app:surface_type="spherical_gl_surface_view"` I can see the streaming and the player follows the direction of the phone sensors. What I need now is to render two images (left and right eye) in the same ExoPlayer to enable the user to watch the streaming with the cardboard headset, like in this image:

[image]